# Using create-react-app with "npm run dev"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am developing a React JS app on a remote server which uses Apache.

In the past I have built a React JS app manually with webpack/babel etc. and then used "npm run dev" to run the app.

With this method I could see any errors on the fly in the terminal and test in the browser automatically through the web browser.

I am now creating a new site with `create-react-app` which takes care of a lot of the tedious setup for you. One thing I cannot figure out is how to use something similar to "npm run dev". My two options seem to be:

- **npm run build** - This takes a while and I have to rerun it every time I change my code. It does put the updated code in the /build directory which I can link to from my Apache server and see in my browser.
- **npm start** - I can see any errors right away in the terminal, but I cannot see it in my browser because it runs on localhost and does not get compiled to the build directory.

What can I do so that I get the best of both worlds? Having quick rebuilds / error reporting and being able to see remotely through my Apache server?

Or would it be better just to go back to my old manual way of doing things?

Comment: Can't you connect to your apache server on the port where your app is running? For instance `localhost:3000` could be `apacheserver.com:3000`.

Comment: @AkshayM I guess part of the problem is that I do not want it to publicly available. With Apache I can add an .htaccess password to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved over the last five years (when this question was posted). It seems to me that `npm start` does the same job as `npm run dev` at least with the latest version of npm and node that i am running. (npm@6.14.18 and node@14.21.3).

When I hit save in my editor (VScode) the terminal (on windows [i haven't tested on Linux]) gets updated right away and so does my browser - errors and all.

Due to the lack of documentation on the `npm run dev` command, one could only assume that it has been deprecated.

Another alternative to the above mentioned commands, would be to use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) which also does a great job of compiling your code, and in my own personal experience has done a better job at tougher projects, than npm.